# IIS 7.5 is prompting for a username and password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

Our application is configured to use Forms Authentication, and on most machines it is working great. However, I am having a problem with the development environment on one of our developer workstations. When I go to one of the URLs of the application, like this:

http://iweb.local/reports/

IIS prompts me for a password, like this:

[image: IIS prompts for a username and password]

*(The name `iweb.local` is set up in the hosts file to point to 127.0.0.1. Essentially it is an alias for localhost. We configure the IIS site to use a host header so we can potentially support more than one application in the future.)*

I am not prompted for a password if I go to most other URLs in the application, such as http://iweb.local/. And I am not prompted for a password anywhere using the exact same code base on any other developer machine. It is only this one machine that is having the problem. This leads me to be reasonably confident that this isn't a problem with the coding.

Things I have tried:

- Testing with a different web browser. On the machine exhibiting the problem, the problem happens no matter what browser I am using. I get the same prompt in FireFox and IE9.
- Testing on other developer machines. The problem doesn't happen on those. It only happens on the single developer box.
- Copying the code and assets from `~/Areas/Reports` into `~/Areas/ReportsTest`, with the appropriate refactors, and loading `http://iweb.local/reportstest/`. That works; the browser no longer prompts for a username and password. However, changing the URL is not an option for our application.
- Checking IIS authentication configuration. Anonymous Authentication and Forms Authentication are enabled. Everything else is disabled. This is identical on all developer machines, including the ones that work and the one that doesn't.
- Checking the Event Log. IIS is not logging anything to the event log.
- Checking the IIS logs. The logs contain entries for successful requests (like when I open `http://iweb.local`), but it does not log anything for any requests that prompt the user to enter a password.
- Checking the request and response headers with FireBug. The request headers seem identical for a request to either URL. The response headers for `http://iweb.local/reports` has two options for `WWW-Authenticate`: `Negotiate` and `NTLM`. From this, I have confirmed that IIS is directing the browser to prompt for a password. But I'm no closer to understanding why.
- Shutting down IIS, setting the World Wide Web Publishing Service to have a Startup Type of Manual so that it won't automatically start up, and rebooting the computer. I then checked to see if either `http://iweb.local` or `http://iweb.local/reports/` were responding to requests. Neither were, confirming that it is IIS that is handling the requests.
- Stopping IIS, deleting the entire project from the developer's hard drive, and retrieving it from source control. My thought here was that it might be a permission issue on one of the folders (though I don't understand how that could be, given that this is an MVC application) and that going through this process would ensure that all folders had the correct permissions. But it didn't change anything.
- Completely uninstalling IIS, restarting the computer, and re-installing IIS. This didn't work either.

I am out of ideas. I cannot find anything on this one developer box that isn't configured the same as the other developer boxes.

So: **Does anyone know a way to enable a deeper level of logging or tracing to figure out why IIS is asking for a password? Can anyone think of anything that may be causing this that I haven't already looked for?**

This is an ASP.NET MVC 3 application running on IIS 7.5 in a 64-bit environment. The `reports` portion of the URL is configured as an MVC Area.

**UPDATE**

In my Web.config file, this is how the authentication mode is set up on the offending machine.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/account/login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

There is no `<authentication>` element in the Web.config file for the Reports area.

Comment: Could `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` be set in your web.config?

Comment: No. In the main Web.config, the `<authentication>` element is set to Forms. There is no `<authentication>` element in the Web.config for the area.

Comment: Maybe it's not the page itself but some asset like js or css caused by NTFS permissions? Do you get 401 if you press cancel? Also have you tried IIS express?

Comment: @Ramunas, that was my thinking when I deleted the whole folder containing the development files for the app and tried retrieving it fresh from source control. Regarding 401: Yes, I still get a 401 if I press cancel. Re: IIS Express, I have not tried that. Can you have that installed along side IIS?

Comment: @CharlieKilian yes, IIS Express can be installed alongside IIS. Use web platform installer

Comment: Does the developer have SQL Server Reporting Services installed? I believe that installs a default Reports Virtual Directory and I know it uses AD authentication by default.

Comment: If you right click on the site in IIS and go to the basic settings and click "Test settings" do authorization and authentication pass?

Comment: @mattytommo, Authentication passes, but Authorization fails with "Cannot verify access to path". However, it does this on all developer machines, even the ones that are working.

Comment: Hmmm I'm suprised it's working at all. Try setting the user on the app pool to be the current window's user.

Comment: @Ramunas, IIS Express is working fine. I'd much prefer to have the developers working off of the full IIS installation so their development environment matches the production environment, but clearly something already isn't matching. At any rate, it's a workaround for now.

Comment: @mattytommo Do you mean to set the app pool user to be the user who is logged in?

Comment: @CharlieKilian That's right yeah.

Comment: @CharlieKilian Are you aware that the settings are inheritated within the a website? So it's may not the application it self.

Comment: @CharlieKilian Could you solve this? I seem to be facing same issue.

Comment: I also had same problem I think there is something with folder name that is 'Reports' I can access all files in other folders but not the files in 'Reports' folder. I just changed the name of folder and Everything is good

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is a folder in the application named "Reports" and SQL Server Reporting Services are installed on the server, then Reporting Services Virtual Directory folder that is also named "Reports" will be in conflict with the application "Reports" folder. To fix this open Reporting Services Configuration Manager (Start->All Programs->MS SQL Server->Configuraton Tools-> Reporting Services Configuration Manager) and change the Virtual Directory from "Reports" to any other name ("TestReports") under the "Report Manager URL" in the menu on the left.

This will solve the IIS authentication issue

Comment: Just want to point out that the "Report Manager URL" setting is different from "Web Service URL" setting. I didn't notice there were 2 URL settings and was confused when it didn't fix the issue after I changed the wrong one.

Comment: This may help (turning off Reporting Services): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281384(v=sql.105).aspx#DisableRM

Comment: This was freaking me out, thought it was something to do with permissions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use fiddler or the dev tools in IE9 to watch the request. This will then show what in the header is causing the pop-up. It could be basic auth, or NT auth where the browser is unable to fulfil the request. As it's localised to the one machine, check IIS is configured to be anonymous only & check the permissions on the file being requested.

Answer (score 0):

In the Location bar, type about:config, and press Enter.

The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click I'll be careful, I promise!, to continue to the about:config page.

In the about:config page, search for the preference network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris, and double-click on it.
In the prompt that comes up, type a list of server you want to allow, separated by a comma and a space. For example, if you wanted to allow http://myinternalserver and http://anotherinternalserver, you would type in myinternalserver, anotherinternalserver.
Press OK.